# console.log is not working after a require statement.in .then function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, require, console.log

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Success!');
});

promise1.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  // const fs = require("fs");
  console.log("yes");
});
```

When require statement is commented, Output is

> "Success!"
> "yes"

But when require statement is uncommented, Output is

> "Success!"

second console.log is not working. Please explain why this is happening and what am i missing.

---

Updated with JS Fiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/shekarmania/wkfjneq7/1

Comment: Please note that require is synchronous, it might take a while to log "yes".

Comment: Can't reproduce on node v12.16.1

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: Try catching errors.

Comment: Where are you executing the code? Jsfiddle run in in the browser, and the browser doesn't support commonJS module and `require` as well

Comment: i am running this code in server, as part of one node process. the code and the behaviour is same. i added jsfiddle snippet for understanding purposes.

Comment: Why are you requiring that package in middle of code in the first place. Please require it at the top of your file